# What is the standard way to use MPI_Isend to send the same message to many processors?

Tags: mpi

I was originally using MPI_Send paired with MPI_Irecv, but I recently found out that MPI_Send may block until the message is received. So, I'm changing to MPI_Isend and I need to send the same message to N different processors. Assuming the buffer will get destroyed later, should I have a for loop with MPI_Isend and MPI_Wait in the loop, or should I make an array of requests and have only MPI_Isend in the loop with MPI_Waitall after the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For distributing the same buffer to "n" remote ranks, MPI_Bcast is the "obvious" choice. Unless you have some "overwhelming" reason to avoid MPI_Bcast, it would be advisable to use it.  In general, MPI_Bcast is very well optimized by all the major MPI implementations.

If blocking is an issue, MPI 3.0 Standard introduced MPI_IBcast along with other non-blocking collectives.  The initial implementation of non-blocking collectives appears to be "naive" and built as wrappers to non-blocking point-to-point routines (e.g. MPI_IBcast is implemented as a wrapper around calls to MPI_ISend and MPI_IRecv).  The implementations are likely to improve in quality over the next year or two - depending partly on the speed of adoption by the MPI application developer community.

MPI_Send will "block" until the send buffer can be safely re-used by the calling application.  Nothing is guaranteed about the state of the corresponding MPI_[I]Recv's.

If you need non-blocking, then the best advice would be to call MPI_ISend in a loop.  Alternatively, persistent requests could be used with MPI_Start or MPI_Startall if this is a message pattern that will be repeated over the course of the program.  [Persistent communication requests.](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node51.html)

Answer (score 2):

Since its the same message, you should be able to use [MPI_Bcast](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Bcast.html). You'll just have to create a new communicator to define a subgroup of processes.

Comment: Wouldn't MPI_Bcast block though?

Comment: Yes, it would. If you're on MPI 3.0 some implementations already have `MPI_Ibcast`.